# Specify database port number in Prestashop 1.6.x

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am currently writing a script to duplicate a legacy 1.6.x Prestashop to a testing environment.

However, I need to specify a **non standard port** (different from 3306) in order to connect to the server containing the MySQL database.

I am  currently trying to do it through the `config/settings.inc.php` file that contains the following :

```php
<?php
define('_PS_CACHING_SYSTEM_', 'CacheMemcache');
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '0');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'MY_DATABASE');
define('_MYSQL_ENGINE_', 'MyISAM');
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'MY_HOST');
define('_DB_USER_', 'MY_USER');
define('_DB_PREFIX_', 'ps_');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'MY_PWD');
define('_COOKIE_KEY_', 'xxx');
define('_COOKIE_IV_', 'xx');
define('_PS_CREATION_DATE_', '2013-03-14');
define('_RIJNDAEL_KEY_', 'xxx');
define('_RIJNDAEL_IV_', 'xx');
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        define('_PS_VERSION_', '1.6.1.13');
```

There is no parameter specify a port number.

I have been researching a solution for that and I found that it is possible with newer versions of Prestashop 1.7.x using the `app/config/parameters.yml`file :

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null  <==
    database_name: prestashop
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    database_prefix: ps_
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

But so far, nothing one 1.6.x versions.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try by adding the port at the end of the _DB_SERVER_ constant like:

```
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'MY_HOST:1234');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for the time saved ! :)